# record is inserted as many times as running the model file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a table sample using db.Model as the following way in model.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/dbname'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class dbconfig(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    host = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False)
    user = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False)
    dbname = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False)
    drivername = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False)
    charset = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False)
    cursorclass = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False)

    def __init__(self,host,password,user,dbname,drivername,charset,cursorclass):

        self.host=host
        self.password=password
        self.user=user
        self.dbname=dbname
        self.drivername=drivername
        self.charset=charset
        self.cursorclass=cursorclass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (self.host,self.user,self.password,self.dbname,self.drivername)

farmautomation = dbconfig('x', 'y','z','xyz','pymysql','utf8mb4','null')
```

Now I am creating table and inserting records with below lines:

```
db.create_all()
db.session.add(farmautomation)
db.session.commit()
dbconfig.query.all()
```

When I run the model.py multiple times the record is inserted the number of times I ran the file, But I need the record to be inserted once even the file is called multiple times, Please let me know how can I approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply count that there are no rows:

```
db.create_all()
rows = dbconfig.query.count()

if rows == 0:
    farmautomation = dbconfig('x', 'y', 'z', 'xyz', 'pymysql', 'utf8mb4', 'null')
    session.add(farmautomation)
    session.commit()
```

You could of course also add filters to the `count` query if you need to be more specific.

Also, I would highly recommend using a configuration file to keep your database credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would store them in confg file

Comment: and, If I insert a new record , Is that inserted for same condition?

Comment: I tried inserting new record and it is not inserted , eg: newrecord=dbconfig( 'x', 'y', 'z', 'xyz', 'pymysql', 'utf8mb4', 'null') and then session.add_all([farmautomation,newrecord])

Comment: Where in your code are you doing this `newrecord`? Also, when do you need to add more rows? When is a row "the same" and you don't need it one more time? Depending on your exact criteria there might be other ways of doing this, like adding unique constraints for host.

Comment: So this is for adding only one record, I got it mate

Comment: Yes the example is very general. If you need the same thing per host (or similar) I was thinking you could add a filter to it, like `rows = dbconfig.query.filter(dbconfig.host == 'x').count()`.